# Delphi with msal Lib for Azure AD (COM)

Tags: c#, delphi, azure-active-directory, com

What is the best way to use msal lib for authentication on azure ad on Delphi (flow with select_account prompt)?
I found only a msal lib for react (javascript), net (c#).

I try to build a C# DLL (.NET Framework 4.6.2) for Com object. The dll works on C# in winforms and on console app. But if i import as type libary on delphi ( i have registred before the dll as com), i dont get "account selection"-window on delphi app. When i call simple function on the C# dll like addition of two numbers or return a string like HelloWorld - this works.

Any ideas what i need to load for get "account selection"-window? Or exist there smart way for authentication on azure ad by delphi?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question.

Your COM DLL approach won't work because the necessary UI logic is contained in the [Microsoft Identity Web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/microsoft-identity-web) middleware built on top of the MSAL library.

There is not an msal-delphi library. So then how to authenticate from a Delphi application to Azure AD? Write an msal-delphi library? No way. And even if you did, you'd have to update it every month with the latest Azure AD updates. So then how?

You want to use the [backend-for-frontend (BFF) architecture](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#name-backend-for-frontend-bff-pr), which is the same [architecture used by the SPA templates in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/intro). It’s also the architecture of the [Azure AD BFF Proxy sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-6-BFF-Proxy) written by [Doğan Erişen](https://www.linkedin.com/in/doganerisen/) earlier this year.

In essence, your Delphi code delegates the logic for authentication (account selection, MFA challenges, protocol communications, everything) to a small ASP.NET Core application using the Microsoft Identity Web middleware. Your Delphi application communicates in some secure way (the BFF IETF doc says traditional browser cookie) with this ASP.NET Core process.

I wrote up the rationale for this design approach (my front end is React) here:
https://mindline.com/august-1-authenticating-enterprise-apps-in-2023/

I wrote a detailed walkthrough of writing the React front end and ASP.NET Core Microsoft Identity Web wrapper here:
https://mindline.com/august-15-authenticating-apps-in-2023-a-closer-look/

Hope this helps.